# Sum and count aggregations over Elasticsearch fields

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-5

I am new to Elasticsearch and I am looking to perform certain aggregations over the fields from an Elasticsearch 5.x index. I have an index that contains the documents with fields `langs` (which have nested structure) and `docLang`. These are dynamically mapped fields. Following are the examples documents

**DOC 1:**

```
{
   "_index":"A",
   "_type":"document",
   "_id":"1",
   "_source":{
      "text":"This is a test sentence.",
      "langs":{
         "X":{
            "en":1,
            "es":2,
            "zh":3
         },
        "Y":{
            "en":4,
            "es":5,
            "zh":6
         } 
      },
      "docLang": "en"
   }
}
```

**DOC 2:**

```
{
   "_index":"A",
   "_type":"document",
   "_id":"2",
   "_source":{
      "text":"This is a test sentence.",
      "langs":{
         "X":{
            "en":1,
            "es":2
         },
         "Y":{
            "en":3,
            "es":4
         } 
      },
      "docLang": "es"
   }
}
```

**DOC 3:**

```
{
   "_index":"A",
   "_type":"document",
   "_id":"2",
   "_source":{
      "text":"This is a test sentence.",
      "langs":{
         "X":{
            "en":1
         },
         "Y":{
            "en":2
         } 
      },
      "docLang": "en"
   }
}
```

I want to perform sum aggregation over the `langs` field in a way that for each key (X/Y) and for each language, I can get the sum across all documents in an index. Also, I want to produce the counts of documents for each type of language from `docLang` field.

e.g.: For above 3 documents, sum aggregation over `langs` field would look like below:

```
"langs":{  
      "X":{  
         "en":3,
         "es":4,
         "zh":3
      },
      "Y":{  
         "en":9,
         "es":9,
         "zh":6
      }
   }
```

And the `docLang` count would look like below:

```
 "docLang":{
    "en" : 2,
    "es" : 1
   }
```

Also because of some production env restrictions, I cannot use scripts in Elasticsearch. So, I was wondering if it is possible to use just `field` aggregation type for above fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "X": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "langs.X"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "X_sum_en": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "langs.X.en"
          }
        },
        "X_sum_es": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "langs.X.es"
          }
        },
        "X_sum_zh": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "langs.X.zh"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Y": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "langs.Y"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "Y_sum_en": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "langs.Y.en"
          }
        },
        "Y_sum_es": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "langs.Y.es"
          }
        },
        "Y_sum_zh": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "langs.Y.zh"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "sum_docLang": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "docLang.keyword",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Since you didn't mention, but I think it's important. I made `X` and `Y` as `nested` fields:

```
    "langs": {
      "properties": {
        "X": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "en": {
              "type": "long"
            },
            "es": {
              "type": "long"
            },
            "zh": {
              "type": "long"
            }
          }
        },
        "Y": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "en": {
              "type": "long"
            },
            "es": {
              "type": "long"
            },
            "zh": {
              "type": "long"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

But, if you fields are not `nested` at all and here I mean actually the `nested` field type in Elasticsearch, a simple aggregation like this one should be enough:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "X_sum_en": {
      "sum": {
        "field": "langs.X.en"
      }
    },
    "X_sum_es": {
      "sum": {
        "field": "langs.X.es"
      }
    },
    "X_sum_zh": {
      "sum": {
        "field": "langs.X.zh"
      }
    },
    "Y_sum_en": {
      "sum": {
        "field": "langs.Y.en"
      }
    },
    "Y_sum_es": {
      "sum": {
        "field": "langs.Y.es"
      }
    },
    "Y_sum_zh": {
      "sum": {
        "field": "langs.Y.zh"
      }
    },
    "sum_docLang": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "docLang.keyword",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```